# Afterwards vs. later

Tags: adverbs

What is the difference between "**[afterwards](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/afterwards)**" and "**[later](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/later?q=LATER)**" in the following sentences:

> 1. We were today in the metro station and **later** in the supermarket.
> 2. We were today in the metro station and **afterwards** in the
>      supermarket.

Practically speaking, can I say that '**later**' means not immediately and '**afterwards**' is immediately? I would like also to know if I can use them interchangeably in the context that I showed.

Comment: No significant difference.  Were you expecting one?

Comment: I thought maybe 'later' means not immediately and 'afterwards' is immediately. Isn't it?

Comment: You need to explain why you are asking. Edit and include your comment in the actual question. And please include dictionary links to both terms.

Comment: Adverbs of time, e.g. yesterday, at 5 o'clock, last year etc. are best placed at the end of a long sentence, or at the beginning, if the sentence is short(ish). *"Today we were in the metro and later in the supermarket"*

Comment: @subtle_sibling  Thanks.  The edited question helps us give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do mean slightly different things although they can be used, as in the original post, to mean the same thing.

**Afterwards** indicates that a specific event has occurred after another specific event.

> "We are going to the movies and **afterwards** we are going out to eat."

If you want string events together in this structure you would do it like this:

> "We are going to the movies and **afterwards** to eat and after that to
>   the zoo and after that to play laser tag."

**Later** merely indicates that something is happening a point in time later then the current point in time.  This can be tied to the order of specific events in the manner of afterwards:

> "We are going to the movies and **later** we're going out to eat"

or it can show the relationship between an event/events and point in time:

> "**Later** we're going out to eat."

You would string events together in this structure like this:

> "**Later** we are going to the movies and even later we are going to
>   the zoo."

You cannot say, "**Afterwards** we are going out to eat," because the listener needs to know, "After what?"

Answer (score -2):

The sentences would mean...

1. You possibly would go anywhere before you went to the supermarket.
2. The supermarket is the next location, you did't go anywhere else after you left the metro station.